# Why does docker-compose say a network is undefined, but "docker network ls" shows it?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have created a network using:

```
docker network create my_network
```

And when I run `docker network ls` I see:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                                                      DRIVER              SCOPE
80e99e7a8f98        bridge                                                    bridge              local
ff48b8c6586b        host                                                      host                local
cdf5969b458d        none                                                      null                local
9bd1e13004b7        my_network                                                bridge              local
```

but when I try to create a redis node using that network, it says:

> Service "redis" uses an undefined network "my_network"

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '2.1'
services:

redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    environment:
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
    networks: 
    - my_network
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define a pre-existing network in your docker-compose file, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

```
networks:
  my_network:
    external:
      name: my_network
```

Comment: Just to check: if the external network were named `my_network_1` and internally, I define the network as `my_network` but set the name to `my_network_1` and in another docker compose define a network `my_network` but that one has name set to `my_network_2`, will they properly be on different networks?

Comment: "my_network" in this case is just a locally scoped to this compose.yml. What really matters is the name of the external declaration. So if network_1 and network_2 both have the same network name for external, they will be on the same network.